# Hyperlink with same width underline

Tags: jquery, html, css

We are developing a site and one of the quirks that we would like to have is links to be underlined when hovered with the line always having the same width no matter how long (or short) the text of the link is.

How would you implement this in CSS/jQuery/Javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/Nm2sD/4/)? This will work unless the anchor element has a smaller width than the background image.

Comment: The text can sometimes be shorter than the line. So I guess, no this will not work?

Comment: Hmm. on a second thought I gave this a try and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

border-bottom is the way to go.

```
<div class="underlined"><a href="#">blah1</a></div>
<div class="underlined"><a href="#">blah1 asdfdf adfefef</a></div>
```

and

```
a:hover {
     text-decoration: none;   
}
a {
     text-decoration: none;   
}
.underlined{
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.underlined:hover
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
}
```

margin-bottom is to keep the size consistent when you add the border.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfV9t/

Comment: I wold add the margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; to center it more for looks than anything especially if the text is longer than the underline

Comment: This won't work if the text is longer than the specified width, as per the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand, but here goes:

Remove the underline for links

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Add it back for links in hover state

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: You should re-read my question again. The underline should have the same width no matter how long the text is. Let's say 300px. Your solution will underline the whole text, so sometimes it will be too long and sometimes too short.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should add this extra info to your question to make it a bit clearer.